# how to create a dictionary from a list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of sentence and I want to convert it into a diction only include the username and the age.

```
list=['@David, the age is 27', '@John, the age is 99', '@rain, the age is 45']
```

The output I want to get is a dictionary like

```
dic={David:27,John:99,rain:45}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Side note: don't shadow built-in `list`, use another variable name, e.g. `lst` or `L`, instead.

Comment: If you have `lst = [["David",27],["John",99],["rain",45]]` then `dic = dict(lst)`. So if you know how to make the nested list, that's one way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a dict comprehension:

`dic = {x.split()[0].strip(',@'): int(x.split()[-1]) for x in member_list}`

If you need clarification on the parts of the expression, please tell.

**EDIT:** Clarification, as required:

Ok, so:

- enclosing the expression in `{}` tells it we are making a dictionary with this comprehension. x represents each member string within this comprehension
- `x.split()` splits the string into a list of substrings, on "space" sign (by default, can be adjusted)

  - with `[0]` we grab the first substring ["@David,"]
  - with `.strip(',@')` we remove the comma and @ character around the name
  - with this we have created the dictionary key
- Key value: `int(x.split()[-1])`

  - `x.split()[-1]` takes the last substring ('27')
  - enclosing it in `int()` we turn it into an integer

Comment: Hi, could you please explain the code steps by steps, sorry I can not quite understand the logic behind. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can define a custom function, apply it to each string via `map`, then feed to `dict`:

```
L = ['@David, the age is 27', '@John, the age is 99', '@rain, the age is 45']

def key_value_extractor(x):
    x_split = x.split(',')  # split by ','
    name = x_split[0][1:]   # take 1st split and exclude first character
    age = int(x_split[1].rsplit(maxsplit=1)[-1])  # take 2nd, right-split, convert to int
    return name, age

res = dict(map(key_value_extractor, L))

{'David': 27, 'John': 99, 'rain': 45}
```

Comment: this is more efficient than mine

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary comprehension

```
l = ['@David, the age is 27', '@John, the age is 99', '@rain, the age is 45']


X = {item.split(',')[0][1:]:int(item.split(',')[1].rsplit(maxsplit=1)[-1]) for item in l}
print(X)

#output
{'David': 27, 'John': 99, 'rain': 45}
```

Comment: sorry fixed the age issue.